# PDO returns "SQLSTATE [HY000]: General Error: 10 Disk I/O error" on sqlite database load

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, pdo, medoo

A bit about my current setup, The website is hosted on a windows server 2012 IIS with PHP 7.1, the site runs using Laravel with Medoo to load the database, however on any form of SQL statement the code fails with the error mentioned in the title.

Currently the file permissions are on Full Control for debug purposes

The code used for the call is the following

```
$pdo = new \Medoo\Medoo([
    'database_type' => 'sqlite',
    'database_file' => $config->database_path
]);

$query = $pdo->select('computers', '*');
```

I have tried making a SQL dump of the SQLite database file using a program called "DB Browser for SQLite" and the making a new database file from scatch then importing the SQL dump.

When this is done the program works without problem, so my current thought is there might be a limit on PDO SQLite file limit size since the original file is about 2.8MB while the new is 1.9MB

Is there anyone who have encounter a similar problem? or have any advice on how to fix the current problem?

Comment: Is the SQLite database readable and writable at the location it resides?

Comment: Pretty much what @JayBlanchard said, are you sure that the user whom the web server runs under has access to the file location of the sql lite database?

Comment: As said in the question the current folder and files have Full Control, as to not encounter that problem